# How do I when pip install dtwalign

Tags: python, pip

```
pip install dtwalign
```

```
DEPRECATION: Python 3.4 support has been deprecated. pip 19.1 will be the last one supporting it. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.4 won't be maintained after March 2019 (cf PEP 429).
Collecting dtwalign
Collecting numba>=0.34.0 (from dtwalign)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from dtwalign) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: seaborn>=0.8.1 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from dtwalign) (0.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from dtwalign) (1.16.6)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from dtwalign) (1.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from dtwalign) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from numba>=0.34.0->dtwalign) (1.1.10)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.4.egg (from numba>=0.34.0->dtwalign) (27.2.0)
Collecting llvmlite>=0.31.0dev0 (from numba>=0.34.0->dtwalign)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/50/cc/04526507e80d546be5688ce0246e40277b61e7949c3347c6609b6a4154cf/llvmlite-0.32.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from numba>=0.34.0->dtwalign) (3.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: funcsigs in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from numba>=0.34.0->dtwalign) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.17.1 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from seaborn>=0.8.1->dtwalign) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from singledispatch->numba>=0.34.0->dtwalign) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.17.1->seaborn>=0.8.1->dtwalign) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.17.1->seaborn>=0.8.1->dtwalign) (2015.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: llvmlite
  Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ufd5rb5f\\llvmlite\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-11jhoxwj' --python-tag cp34:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  c:\anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ufd5rb5f\llvmlite\ffi\build.py
  Trying generator 'Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ufd5rb5f\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 192, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ufd5rb5f\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 180, in main
      main_win32()
    File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ufd5rb5f\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 89, in main_win32
      generator = find_win32_generator()
    File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ufd5rb5f\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 77, in find_win32_generator
      try_cmake(cmake_dir, build_dir, generator)
    File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ufd5rb5f\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 28, in try_cmake
      subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '-G', generator, cmake_dir])
    File "c:\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 556, in check_call
      retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    File "c:\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in call
      with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
    File "c:\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
      restore_signals, start_new_session)
    File "c:\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
      startupinfo)
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
  error: command 'c:\\anaconda3\\python.exe' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for llvmlite
  Running setup.py clean for llvmlite
Failed to build llvmlite
Installing collected packages: llvmlite, numba, dtwalign
  Found existing installation: llvmlite 0.20.0
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
``
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you are using python 3.4, which is not officially supported by `dtwalign` and also Deprecated as a whole? You might have an easier time to upgrade to a different python version

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you first install pandas library.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html

You can then install dtwalign python with following command(administrator):
pip install dtwalign

Errors should then be solved.